# Does transaction hash in Ropsten ( testnet) deprecate ever?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, etherscan, ropsten

I want to know whether transaction hash created in testnet stay forever or after sometime it gets deleted? Like in IPFS garbage collector deletes unpinned files after two weeks. IPFS is also decentralized.

Comment: Stays forever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory once a transaction hash is given it stays forever. However in the case of testnets the rule of thumb is that you should never rely on something staying forever.

They are called test nets for a reason. They may get screwed up (and have been screwed up many times in the past) for whatever test reasons. Typically they get screwed due to a test of an incoming hard fork but there may be other reasons as well.

IPFS decentralization and Ethereum decentralization are rather different kinds of decentralizations in my opinion (Ethereum's being much stronger) but that's a topic for another discussion.